# SEO friendly URL and site structure for an anagram site?

Tags: seo, url, search-results

Quoting [Googles Doorway pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721312) guidelines:

> Substantially similar pages that are closer to search results than a
>   clearly defined, browseable hierarchy

In case of a site such as Anagram solver - A user types in a word or a sentence in a search box on the main page and gets back a list of anagrams for that query.
Currently each query has its own url (*://domain/{query}).

Reading the above guidelines, I think the site pages can fall under the category of "doorway pages". 
What should be the right URL hierarchy in such case in order to achieve the following:

1. Users can share URL of a specific query with other users.
2. Specific queries are being indexed and not considered as doorway pages.

Currently, the site is being crawled, but only pages I explicitly request indexing for using "fetch as google" are being indexed.

Sitemap of all URL queries with more than 2 results has been submitted.

The site: [Hebrew Anagram solver website](http://www.anagram.co.il)

Comment: It doesn't look good for your site when I can put in spam like "viagra casino xxx" and get a page Google could crawl.   That is enough to get your entire site kicked out of the search results.   Google site reviewers have been known to try that.